# ASP.NET Core IdentityDbContext using dependency Injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

It's any possible to using new dependency injection mechanism in ASP.NET Core to inject IdentityDbContext into my repository?

EF version:

```
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
```

Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>,       IApplicationDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) => base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Repository:

```
 public class CustomerRepository: ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CustomerRepository(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

How to configure Startup.cs?

I have basic configuration

```
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

this does not work:

```
        services.AddTransient<IApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need to define `IApplicationDbContext` in order for the dependency injection framework to work.

You can try

**Startup.cs**:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

    // You can actually use
    // Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") here instead to simplify the code
```

If you look at the second parameter of `AddDbContext()`, `ServiceLifetime` is set to `Scoped`, which means the object instance will be the same within the same request, but different among different requests.

If you want to the DI framework to create different instances every single time, you can set the second parameter to `Transient`.

**Repository**:

```
public class CustomerRepository: ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CustomerRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

The DI framework will inject `ApplicationDbContext` for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `services.AddTransient<IApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();` syntax asks the dependency injection block to directly instantiate `ApplicationDbContext`, which bypasses the DB context factory set up by EntityFramework.

Instead, you can use this syntax, that will preserve how `ApplicationDbContext` is internally registered by `AddDbContext`:

```
services.AddTransient<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>());
```